# Any free application to redirect serial communication to TCP/IP?

Tags: windows, tcpip, serial-port

Please can anyone suggest a free application which creates virtual serial ports and any traffic on that port is redirected to given TCP/IP address?

Comment: TCP/IP over Serial Line: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking/tcpip/ch06_02.htm? As in SLIP/PPP...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is for Windows, then see [HW VSP3 - Virtual Serial Port](http://www.hw-group.com/products/hw_vsp/index_en.html)

> HW VSP is a software driver that adds
>   a virtual serial port (e.g. COM5) to
>   the operating system and redirects the
>   data from this port via a TCP/IP
>   network to another hardware interface,
>   which is specified by its IP address
>   and port number.

**Main Features**

- Free, unrestricted Virtual Serial Port driver for any TCP/IP devices
- Compatible with Windows 2000, XP (Win 98, NT) and Windows Vista
- Runs as a standalone application, or as a NT service suitable for servers
- Option to start at Windows startup and minimize to System Tray
- Single-port (free) and multi-port (commercial) version
- Supports RFC 2217, allowing to change remote serial port parameters (such as speed, parity, stop bits) over TCP using NVT
- VSP driver typically operates as a “TCP client”; however, it can also be used as a “TCP server” (useful for GPRS applications)
- Configuration stored in an INI file
- Configuration protected with a password
- Supports UAC (User Account Control – user switching in Windows XP and Vista)
- This software is FREEWARE, as long as you comply with the license terms and conditions

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/), Null-modem emulator, also includes COM to TCP redirection.

> The Null-modem emulator can be used to provide serial interface for COM port redirectors. For example, with the com2tcp ( COM port to TCP redirector, part of the  com0com project ) you can communicate via serial interface with the TCP/IP servers.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [TCPCOM32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpcom32/) and there are also some other projects at [SourceForge](http://www.sourceforge.net) which are doing such a thing.

Also, what operating system?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [perle trueport](https://www.perle.com/downloads/trueport.shtml) to connect to a ser2net server. Trueport is RFC2217 compliant, which means you can use any baudrate you want.