# TCP socket to serial port

Tags: tcp, sockets, serial

Is is possibile to remotely access a serial port by tcp socket server? Exists this kind of software?
It is the opposit of this question:
[Any free application to redirect serial communication to TCP/IP?](https://superuser.com/questions/54723/any-free-application-to-redirect-serial-communication-to-tcp-ip)
I have a real-serial-port and I want to write and read from it using a remote socket.

Comment: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/11543/remote-serial-connection-redirected-over-network-using-ssh might be relevant

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with the Virtual Serial Ports Emulator from www.eterlogic.com. VSPE provides a TCP Socket to Com Port connection. It's a free app for 32 bit systems but there is a fee of $25 to run on 64 bit OS.